# Using spread operator during Vue Component creation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vue-i18n

I'm trying to close the configuration options of the `vue-i18n` behind a helper method that will generate them and use during creating Vue component.

If I'm setting the configuration options directly - everything is working. After moving the configuration into separate helper method the feature is

This is working:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Products',
  nuxtI18n: {
    paths: {
      'de/de': '/produkte',
      'ch/en': '/products',
      'ch/de': '/produkte',
      'eu/en': '/products',
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is not working:

```
<script>
const i18nPathTranslator = ({ en = false, de = false }) => ({
  nuxtI18n: {
    paths: {
      'de/de': de,
      'ch/en': en,
      'ch/de': de,
      'eu/en': en,
    }
  }
})

export default {
  name: 'Products',
  ...i18nPathTranslator({
    en: '/products',
    de: '/produkte'
  })
}
</script>
```

The result of the second code example is that the routes are not affected by the provided instructions.

Comment: _`({ en: false, de: false })`_  really not sure what that's supposed to be but it triggers an error for me ~ _"SyntaxError: false is an invalid identifier"_

Comment: Sorry - that was the mistake I've done during edititng the question - it should be the default values.